# SpiderMonkey Build Configure Error "configure: error: Your C and C++ compilers are different..."

Tags: firefox, compiler-errors, spidermonkey

Command:
`mozjs-38.0.0/js/src/build_DBG.OBJ$ ../configure --enable-debug --disable-optimize`

Output:
`...
configure:3223: checking for windres
configure: error: Your C and C++ compilers are different.  You need to use the same compiler.`

The gcc and g++ version is 4.9.3.Clang version is 3.6.0-2.

How to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to update your gcc and g++.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by link "/usr/bin/c++" from "/etc/alternatives/c++" to the currently used g++.